# Why move assignment in my class wasn't called?

Tags: c++, oop, move-semantics, move-constructor, copy-elision

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;

struct BigInteger
{
    vector<int> arr;

    BigInteger()
    {
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
        this->arr.push_back(0);
    }
    BigInteger(initializer_list<int> il)
    {
        cout << "initializer_list constructor" << endl;
        for (const int x : il)
        {
            arr.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    BigInteger(const BigInteger& obj) //copy constructor
    {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
        this->arr = obj.arr; 
    }
    BigInteger(BigInteger&& obj) //move constructor
    {
        cout << "move constructor" << endl;
        swap(*this, obj);
    }
    ~BigInteger() //destructor
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
        arr.clear(); //probably because of RAII, I guess I don't have to write this
    }
    BigInteger& operator=(const BigInteger& rhs)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment" << endl;
        BigInteger tmp(rhs);
        this->arr = tmp.arr;
        return *this;
    }
    BigInteger& operator=(BigInteger&& rhs) noexcept 
    {
        cout << "move assignment" << endl;
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BigInteger another = BigInteger({0, 1, 2});
}
```

So, I'm creating a temporary object `BigInteger({0, 1, 2})` and then doing the move assignment for my class instance `a` (theoretically). So expected output is:

> initializer_list constructor //creating temporary object
>
> default constructor //creating glvalue (non-temporary) object
>
> move assignment
>
> destructor

But the output is:

> initializer_list constructor
>
> destructor

And I don't even understand why is that happening. I suspect that `operator=` is not the same as initialization, but still I don't understand how my object is constructed.

Comment: You're right, assignment is separate from initialization. The `=` in the syntax is a red herring.

Comment: @Frank so copy elision is somewhat direct initialization of my data members? can I somehow explicitly forbid copy elision?

Comment: @Learpcs since C++17, `BigInteger another = BigInteger({0, 1, 2});` gets compiled as if it were written as `BigInteger another({0, 1, 2});`, so there is no temp `BigInteger` object to optimize away. You can't forbid this, you can only work around it, such as by saving `BigInteger({0, 1, 2})` to another variable first, or moving it into a function and then initializing `another` from the return of that function. But even then, copy elision is going to try to optimize away the temp `BigInteger` object. You can't disable copy elision, but there are ways to make it unfeasible in some contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primarily, move assignment operator isn't called because you aren't assigning anything. `Type name = ...;` is initialisation, not assignment.

Furthermore, there isn't even move construction because `BigInteger({0, 1, 2})` is a prvalue of the same type as the initialised object, and thus no temporary object will be materialised, but rather the the initialiser of the prvalue is used to initialise `another` directly, as if you had written `BigInteger another = {0, 1, 2};` (which is incidentally what I recommend that you write; There's simply no need to repeat the type).

> I suspect that operator= is not the same as initialization

This is correct. Assignment operator and initialisation are two separate things. You aren't using the assignment operator in this example.

Comment: So, I'm using initialisation. But how is it implemented? Does it use copy elision? Does it use my copy/move constructors? (due to my output I suspect the answer to third question is no)

Comment: `Does it use copy elision?` Before C++17, it would have (potentially) used copy elision optimisation. But since C++17 it is no longer an optimisation, but rather the behaviour is specified in the language. `Does it use my copy/move constructors?` See the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I have one question about line `BigInteger another = {0, 1, 2};`. Why does it work? Does it use my initializer_list constructor? if yes, then `BigInteger another = {0, 1, 2};` and `BigInteger another {0, 1, 2};` are semantically the same? I didn't implemented `operator=(initalizer_list<int> l)`. UPD: actually we don't need to implement the `operator=(initalizer_list<int> l)` because as we said it's NOT initialization.

Comment: @Learpcs Yes, if you have an `std::initializer_list` constructor, then a braced initialiser list will invoke that constructor. Yes, those two are semantically the same. Indeed, since it's not an assignment, no `operator=` will be called.

Comment: @Learpcs "*I didn't implemented `operator=(initalizer_list<int> l)`*" - `operator=` is NEVER used during *initialization*, only during *assignment*.  `BigInteger another = {0, 1, 2};` is *initialization*, not *assignment*. You need to understand the distinction between the two. *Initialization* is used only while creating a new object. *Assignment* is used only while updating an existing object.

Answer (score 1):

> So, I'm creating a temporary object BigInteger({0, 1, 2}) and then
> doing the move assignment for my class instance a (theoretically).

Is seems you mean the move constructing instead of the move assignment because you are speaking about a declaration.

From the C++ 14 Standard (12.8 Copying and moving class objects)

> 31 When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
> the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
> selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
> object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
> source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
> different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
> that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
> would have been destroyed without the optimization.122 This elision of
> copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the
> following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple
> copies):
>
> (31.3) — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a
> reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
> cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
> constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
> omitted copy/move

So in this declaration

```
BigInteger another = BigInteger({0, 1, 2});
```

the move operation is omitted by the constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move.